# Why is my program slowing my computer to an unuseable speed

Tags: java

So I am just starting to learn java and I am following a video tutorial on youtube. I am trying to run this code and it runs, but it slows my computer down and then freezes everything after less than a second. What is wrong with it? I also don't know if this is relevant, but I am currently running this on a linux machine.

```
package com.matt.rain;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static int width = 300;
public static int height = width / 16 * 9;
public static int scale = 3;

private Thread thread;
private JFrame frame;
private boolean running = false;

public Game() {
    Dimension size = new Dimension(width * scale, height * scale);
    setPreferredSize(size);

    frame = new JFrame();
}


public synchronized void start() {
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this, "Display");
    thread.start();
}

public synchronized void stop() {
    running = false;
    try{
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void run(){
    int x = 1;
    while (running == true){
        System.out.println("Running..."+ x);
        update();
        render();
        x = x + 1;
    }
}

public void update(){


}

public void render(){
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    Game game = new Game();
    game.frame.setResizable(false);
    game.frame.setTitle("Rain");
    game.frame.add(game);
    game.frame.pack();
    game.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    game.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    game.frame.setVisible(true);

    game.start();

}
}
```

Comment: Because you are updating your Canvas at maximum speed, which in turn invokes acquiring and releasing a Graphics object, among many other things. I suggest you look into javax.swing.Timer.

Answer (score -1):

You may resolve the problem by using `sleep()` inside the while loop in run().

```
while (running == true){
    // System.out.println("Running..."+ x);
    try{Thread.sleep(50);}catch(Exception e){}
    update();
    render();
    x = x + 1;
}
```

Adding `sleep()` will allow other threads to work along with your program, therefore not causing your computer to stop responding.

Though, I think that `sleep()` is not very accurate. For accurate timing you may have to use some other method.

Comment: GUIs and sleep() do not mix.

Comment: @EJP Thanks for the info. I am not sure though that it applies here, because the sleep in being called on a separate thread, not on the UI thread. Therefore it will not block EDT.

Comment: The code in the `render()` method assumes it *is* being called on the EDT.

Comment: @EJP What do you mean by assumes! In the code above the sleep is called on thread different from ETD. Are you sure you know what you are saying? And also `sleep` is not in `render()` it is in `run()` of a thread. Please do not follow things blindly because you read it somewhere.